Looking the author of specific position
Who is the author of the following study? In which white moves and wins:
[FEN "8/8/7B/K7/8/7p/4Bkp1/6Rb w KQkq - 0 1"]


Searched HHdbVI with CQL, but couldn't find any matches.

Searching the fen in Google returned this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ORxntNz9mHs

@emdio yep. That video is Greek, and the creator mentions near the end: "I'm not sure who created this study - if you know, please add a comment so that I can update the title of this course."

not in PDB or WinChloe, afaics

Searching for the first few moves of the solution led to this page which attributes the study to J. Behting (1892):  https://talkchess.com/viewtopic.php?t=34892
This position was the topic of an earlier Chess Stack Exchange question "I'm struggling to find the full solution of a chess problem", but there the question of authorship was neither raised nor answered.
[added later: I looked at the Youtube video (ORxntNz9mHs) that emdio found.
It's Greek to me too, but I see that the caption includes
"Β. Μπέτινγκ 1890", which more-or-less corroborates the
talkchess attribution since Μπέτινγκ ~ Behting
(modern Greek uses Μπ for a B sound, since β is v),
though the initial B doesn't match Karl and the date is two years off.]
